# Tracking WordPress tags in Google Analytics with Google Tag Manager

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

On a WordPress site I've got Google Tag Manager (GTM) with Universal Analytics 
tag. I'm also tracking some custom events. It's working fine.

I'd like to track for each single-post pageview also the WordPress tags of that post.
I've already inserted a javascript on my site that, when page is loaded, extracts the tags information from html and pushes it to the dataLayer, this way:

```
    if ($('body').hasClass("single")) {  // only on single post pages
        var $t = "";
        $(this).find(".tag a").each(function(){
            $temp= $(this).attr("href");
            $temp= $temp.replace("https://example.com/tag/","");
            $temp= $temp.replace("/","");
            $t += ($t!="" ? "," :"") + $temp;
        });
        console.log($t); // smartphone,tech,iphone
        dataLayer.push({
          'pageAttributes' : $t.split(","),
        });
    }
```

I can see in the javascript console the WordPress tags correctly parsed and I can see them in the dataLayer javascript object.
I've added a Custom Dimension in Google Analytics, I have named it just "tag", it's the Dimension 1 in my GA property:

[image: Custom Dimension in GA]

In GTM I've created a variable in which I put the pageAttributes read from dataLayer.

[image: Variable in Google Tag Manager that pick WordPress tags from dataLayer]

I've then modified in GTM the Universal Analytics tag used to track the site in Google Analytics, by activating the override of the settings and adding my Custom Dimension 1 from {{wp tags}} variable.
[image: Universal Analytics tag modified to track custom dimension]

Since there are no data in Google Analytics about WordPress tags, I think something is wrong. Maybe the override of the settings in GTM happens before my javascript has setted up the pageAttributes variable in dataLayer and then the {{wp tags}} in GTM.

How can I tell GTM to send WordPress post tags data placed in dataLayer to the Google Analytics pageview?

Giulio

Comment: At what point during the page load are you pushing the tags to the DL? You should also push an event to the DL, alongside the tag data, so that you can use that event as the trigger for your tag.

Comment: We don't see your trigger - you have to remember that you can query the DOM only if it's actually loaded, so you'd need to use a DOM Ready trigger rather than the pageview. Also there is processing latency, so data might not show up immediateley.

Comment: I've removed the override of the main Universal Analytics tag and I've added the tracking of the {{wp tags}} variable with a new Universal Analytics pageview tag, activated by an event. I can see the event in the gtm debugger, and I can see the pageAttributes array of tag in the debugger. I think I have to wait some time (one day) before I can see data in Google Analytics.

Comment: I just have a doubt: by using another Universal Analytics tag for pageview do I risk to count each page twice?